# I am trying to read the SOL/ Token transaction for a account. How to interpret the content in the image below?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

[image]

async function getTransactionHistory(address){

```
let addr = new web3.PublicKey(address)

let txns = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(addr,{limit:1})
let txnList = txns.map(transaction => transaction.signature)
console.log(txnList.length)
let txDetails = await connection.getParsedTransactions(txnList)
console.log(txDetails)
txDetails.forEach((transaction,i)=>{
    console.log("Post Balance : ",transaction.meta.postBalances)
    console.log("Pre Balance : ",transaction.meta.preBalances)

})
```

}
getTransactionHistory('')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `transaction.message` you can find `accountKeys` those are the accounts for the `postBalance` and `preBalance` in order. This means the first `preBalance` and `postBalance` are for the first `account` in `accountKeys`.

**example**

doing this in rust, but it's gonna be similar in typescript since they both invoke the Solana JSON RPC API.

```
{
account_keys: [
    ParsedAccount {
        pubkey:  "9FunJaYzY97hcTNN95mAn8iEhXQjw9NpKDmng8NYLAbt",
        writable: true,
        signer: true 
    },
    ParsedAccount {
        pubkey: "CXFCTHyuhcJL3fiFR5eRochz4k9dwzZWfLMU7knzaCp",
        writable: true,
        signer: false
    }],
}
```